# How to reflect initial value of a Form in Angular 8 in an input?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material2

I inserted a `Datepicker` on my Angular site following [this link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) as follows:

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100 form-control" color="secondary">
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerStart" name="startDate"
           [formControl]="f.startDate"
           (click)="pickerStart.open()">
       <fa-icon [icon]="faCalendar" size="lg" (click)="pickerStart.open()"
           class="mat-datepicker-toggle"></fa-icon>
       <mat-datepicker #pickerStart></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-error *ngIf="f.startDate.hasError('required')">Start date is required.</mat-error>
```

The `ts` code:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
     startDate: [ moment().subtract(1, 'months').format('DD/MM/YYYY'), [Validators.required]]
   });
}

get f() { return this.form.controls; }
```

But my initial value on the `Datepicker` is not initializing.

Why is it not being displayed? I know the value is correctly set as it's being used in another place of typescript and it's being set. But not displayed. Any help?

**Edit:** I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128447/how-to-initialize-an-angular-material-datepicker-input-form-field) answer on Stackoverflow, but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit [DatePicker on Angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-selected-date)  for more info but this worked for me

Try using `startDate: [ moment().subtract(1, 'months').toISOString(), [Validators.required]]`

Comment: setting string will help, try it out as Musa mentioned.

Comment: for more info on _d [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i)